# Getting application folder path on MeteorJS?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, meteor, filepath

In Meteor I've been looking for a way to get the home folder of the running Meteor application in Server.

For example, if my `.meteor` folder is in `C:/Users/Me/Repos/MyWebsite/.meteor`, is there a way to get the path `C:/Users/Me/Repos/MyWebsite/`, or where ever the app is currently running at?

The reason I am asking this is because I am running some scripts with my webapp, and if the script (let's call it script.rb) is in a folder called `util` in the Meteor home folder, I have to hardcode the entire path `C:/Users/Me/Repos/MyWebsite/utils/script.rb`

Is there a better way to do this?

As a side note, this must all be made server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are here: `projectRoot/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/shell-server.js`

So, to reference a script that lives in a sibling folder of your project, it'll look something like this: `../../../../../../scriptFolder/script.rb`

Comment: Is that really the only way to do it? It seems like a brute force method.